# Is it possible to call Black as an API?

Tags: python, python-black

Say I want to use [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as an API, and do something like:

```
import black

black.format("some python code")
```

Formatting code by calling the `black` binary with `Popen` is an alternative, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: you may certainly need to give black a file. Because it parses the grammar based on the code and take indentation into consideration and stuff. You can see the [code](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/3dc461a41a13cc36303aff80d079786ef210ddae/blib2to3/pgen2/grammar.py#L97)

Comment: there is [blackd](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/blackd.html), but that's probably even worse than using a subprocess.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could try using `format_str`:

```
from black import format_str, FileMode
res = format_str("some python code", mode=FileMode())
print(res)
```

Comment: @laike9m not that I'm aware, but you [can see](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/master/black.py#L424) that it is what is used if you supply the `--code` command line argument.

Answer (score 6):

Use `black.format_file_contents`.

*e.g.*

```py
import black

mode = black.FileMode()
fast = False
out = black.format_file_contents("some python code", fast, mode)
```

https://github.com/psf/black/blob/19.3b0/black.py#L642

Comment: does not work for me make last line
out     = black.format_file_contents( "ex_black.py", fast = True , mode = mode )

Comment: @russ_hensel You have to pass the *contents* of the python module instead of the path of the python module. If you want to format using the path, use the [format_file_in_place function](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/19.3b0/black.py#L642)

Answer (score 2):

It's [not officially supported](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#does-black-have-an-api), but you can call `black.format_file_contents` as seen in the [`black.format_stdin_to_stdout`](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/27d20144a7517594e24a1649451177b2a11284be/src/black/__init__.py#L870) function.

When simplified, it's only following few lines:

```py
import black  # version: 22.10.0

BLACK_MODE = black.Mode(target_versions={black.TargetVersion.PY311}, line_length=120)

code = ...  # some python code to reformat

try:
    code = black.format_file_contents(code, fast=False, mode=BLACK_MODE)
except black.NothingChanged:
    pass
finally:
    # Make sure there's a newline after the content
    if code and code[-1] != "\n":
        code += "\n"

print(code)  # print result
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Does Black have an API?

> Not yet. *Black* is fundamentally a command line tool. Many [integrations](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/index.html) are provided, but a Python interface is not one of them. A simple API is being [planned](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/779) though.

For now, you should call black using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). The other answers which `import black` are unsupported and likely to break without warning.

Watch issue [*Black's public API #779*](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/779) for possible further developments.

(source: the same question in black's [FAQ](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#does-black-have-an-api) page)