# How to run `python -m <module>`?

Tags: python, pyodide

How can I run `python -m black` (or pass Python code as input to `main` function of `black` to get formatted output) **in Pyodide**?

- [Pyodide demo](https://wasmeditor.com/)

I'm hoping to add a "Format" button to the bottom next to "Run". How to run `black` is the issue. I can set the textarea contents with JavaScript.

I can install [`black-22.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/51/1f7f93c0555eaf4cbb628e26ba026e3256174a45bd9397ff1ea7cf96bad5/black-22.12.0-py3-none-any.whl) [since it is a pure Python wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64407516/9196691) (ends with `none-any.whl`).

[`python -m <module>` runs module as a script](https://linux.die.net/man/1/python):

> -m *module-name*
>     Searches *sys.path* for the named module and runs the corresponding *.py* file as a script.

Pyodide docs:

- [Quick start](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/quickstart.html#complete-example)
- [API](https://micropip.pyodide.org/en/stable/project/api.html)
- [JS API](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/js-api.html)

It is possible to run arbitrary Python code and install Python wheels in Pyodide. Pyodide also has a virtual file system.

It is also possible to [call `black` as an API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57652922/9196691), but in this case, how can I safely escape the input (by users)?

Answer (score 3):

`python -m xxx` just imports the module and runs it as if it were the main program.  Since the `__main__` part of black just says:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    patched_main()
```

you can simulate that by doing:

```
import black
black.patched_main()
```

The `runpy.run_module` API can be used to simulate `python -m`, but in this case I don't think you need that at all.